# Historic Time Series Data for entire Tech Sector on Aikon

Tags: time-series, historical-data, analysis

I am attempting to gather data for my dissertation on daily closing prices for all 1700ish companies within the US tech sector. Now, doing this one by one through something like datastream is going to take me absolutely forever, hence the question: does anyone know how I could extract all this data in a concise and quick manner?

Thanks in advance!